# Unable to publish to Azure website

Tags: visual-studio-2010, publish, azure-web-app-service

I successfully published several projects to Azure websites a few weeks ago.
Then I worked with cloud services and it also worked very well.
But yesterday, when I tried to publish a new Silverlight project to a new Azure website, I couldn't get it to work.

I downloaded the publish profile from my Azure dashboard and then I imported this profile into my VS project.

After that, if I select "Web Deploy" as the publish method, all fields are filled (service URL, user name, etc.) but when I hit "Validate connection", I get the following error message:

> The target "MSDeployTestCOnnection" does not exist in the project

And if I select "FTP" as the publish method, I have to fill the fields and then the connection is validated.
But if I try to publish, I get the following error:

> The target "GatherAllFilesToPublish" does not exist in the project.

And I just can't remember any change I could have made on my computer since the last time this worked...

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the free version of Visual Studio (Express)?

Try removing the following Web Publish files:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/116d3562-99fb-45b0-acf9-b35bc393682e

Comment: No, I don't have the Express version of VS. And I don't have a "new web publish form" like the guy on the thread you linked. So I won't uninstall something that was working until yesterday. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you download/update to the new SDK perhaps? What version of Visual Studio are you running?  When you build the application can you manually upload the Cloud project using the Azure portal?

Comment: I've got "Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - June 2012 v1.7.50517.1601" which seems to be the latest version. And I'm using VS 2010 Pro with SP1. I guess everything is up-to-date. And from what I understand, there's no way to upload my project to my Azure website through the portal. There's no "upload" button like with cloud services.

Comment: My bad. I've just installed Azure Tools from October 2012. But I'm still giving up.